# MVVM Dynamic Menu with Binding (with out HierarchicalDataTemplate)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu

I need MVVM Dynamic Menu without HierarchicalDataTemplate. I do not know is that possible and  if it is how to do that?

Comment: I you really want to get an answer here, you'd better give us a proper question. Please explain your requirements clearly and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Did you tried WPF `Menu` and `MenuItem` to check if it is possible or not ?

Comment: Yes I want Menu and MenuItem but organized dinamically in xaml but not with HierarchicalDataTemplate. Something with ItemsControl or some control like that.

Comment: `Menu` *is* an `ItemsControl`. If it isn't hierarchical, you can just use a `DataTemplate`, or even set the `DisplayMemberPath`.